# Toilet paper orientation

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin, modern-life, technology

Toilet paper orientation is the source of some amount of debate, and it turns out it even has [a dedicated Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet_paper_orientation).
For reasons partly beyond my comprehension, I would like to describe this issue in Latin.
My main motive is to be able to describe such mundane "geometrical" things in Latin in a natural way.

I only want to do it very simply, so my aim is to translate the following:

> A roll of toilet paper can be put in its holder in two ways.
>   The more popular orientation is the "over" orientation where the paper comes from above the roll.
>   In the "under" orientation the paper is against the wall.

It is not important to translate word by word, but to describe the same thing in Latin.
Here is my attempted translation:

> Charta latrinalis duobus modis in capulo suo poni potest.
>   Orientatio popularior, "orientatio superna" appellata, talis est, ut pars chartae capienda super volumen chartae iaceat.
>   In altera orientatione, quae "orientatio subterna" appellatur, charta capienda inter parietem et volumen est.

How would you improve or comment this translation?
I think it gets the point across, but choices of words and descriptions of the orientation options could probably be improved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fieri solet ut charta mundatoria sit in capulo binis modibus ponenda. In vulgus gratus est modus quo charta procidit summo de volumine. In altero modo retro decidit charta iuxta parietem.

I think that you need to keep it simple, without inventing such a word as *orientatio*. Would *cursus* be neater, do you think?